# How can I "move from comments to chat"?

Tags: discussion, chat, user-interface

Someone dropped a link to a chat in response to a comment (presumably in order to not overload the comment format). But I can't seem to be able to do anything but **view** that chat. Am I supposed to response in chat, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking in chat requires at least 20 reputation points, but you are at 67 so that shouldn't be the issue. All that remains, I think, is to be logged in and on the right page. The chat service is actually on a different set of servers and requires a login separate from (but linked to) your SE site user account.

The page you are looking at may be one of two things:

- It may be the transcript page, in which case you need to look for the "join X users in this room" button to jump from the log to the actual chat interface.
- It may be the chat interface, but you are not logged in, in which case you need to find the login function to enable the talk features.

Comment: Thank you. I may have been somehow logged out, as I now see a chat box where I can type answers. Weird.

Comment: Actually, I somehow ended up again on a page where I can't reply, and it was a transcript page. I think there's no clearly visble link from the transcript page to the chat page, which is a hinderance.

Comment: @user4813 You might be right on that. I think the link is the room name, but that might be a usability issue to mention in a post on [meta.se]. The flow there is certainly not as obvious as it could be.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Does this chat follow a template (so it's a Stackexchange-wide problem)?

Comment: @user4813 Yes the chat system is network-wide. Each site has a few CSS tweaks but it's the same system.